# Можно ли в документах писать "проверка правильности"?

Tags: лексика

Можно ли в документах писать "проверка правильности документов" (по отношению к первичным документам, имеется в виду проверка оформления и заполнения). И если это некорректная формулировка, то как можно написать по-другому? Формулировка нужна для текста приложения к договору.

Comment: «Проверку» можно заменить «контролем», а при некоторых обстоятельствах — «аудитом». А если «имеется в виду "проверка оформления и заполнения"», то так и надо писать, не экономя слов.

Comment: Первый раз слышу о таком приложении к договору.Такая формулировка только в документах проверяющих организаций: Приложение 2. Проверка правильности оформления документов, применяемых для целей контроля в рамках ТБВК 
 http://base.garant.ru/777403/56ae36fc84d31bc2f9c0b07177fa16a9/?vk#ixzz6ks0WaALX  В договорах может быть перечень  предоставленных документов (наличие их, чтоб не потерялись), различные акты, а правильность документов просто проверяют без бумаг, если что неправильно - переписывают. Зачем там указывать, какой документ неправильно оформлен?